# Keycloak doesn't redirects in development

Tags: keycloak, ktor

I've just started Keycloak for the first time (newbie) with a docker container on port 10080. And setup a new realm, client, user and a attached it to a role/group. Everything till now is fine and working without any issue.

In the client setup of Keycloak I've set the `Valid Redirect URIs` to my application to `http://localhost:8080/*` and when I'm call the the auth page of my webserver I get a error message from Keycloak `Invalid parameter: redirect_uri` and if I setup the `URI` to `*` its working but the Keycloak doesn't redirects to port 8080 and redirects to `:10080/oauth?state=1c7` and if I'm just replacing the port with my webservice it shows the auth token, which I've setup for testing to show the payload from Keylcloak.

**Somehow the redirects doesn't work**! If I'm putting the wrong credentials for my user its working perfectly with error message, which is the expected behaviour.

I've also setup the root and admin url in the client setup to be on the save side ¯_(ツ)_/¯

My docker-compose:

```
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.0
    container_name: keycloak_abc
    ports:
      - "10080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      - abc-network
```

The response from Keycloak after login with a valid user and redirect url set to `*` : 
http://localhost:10080/oauth?state=768038c4a2adb8dd&session_state=e64e00d9-f3d0-4c0a-9df0-42cab897be08&code=47cd4e1c-ff62-46c1-a681-182a83b6aeb4.e64e00d9-f3d0-4c0a-9df0-42cab897be08.7006377e-2f0d-4b56-b3e5-991f8036fb11

I've uploaded a recording from the network traffic: https://pastebin.com/v3yqcUh7

Comment: Can you show us the url of your request. Redirect url should be in the url params.

Comment: @andrija I've updated the Q

Comment: You sent wrong return url :
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A10080%2Foauth        
You should send the address of your application, not Keycloak address.

Comment: Its working now thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's working!

```
    install(Authentication) {
        oauth(keycloakOAuth) {
            client = HttpClient(Apache)
            providerLookup = { keycloakProvider }
            urlProvider = { "http://localhost:8080/oauth" }
        }
    }
```

I've updated the urlProvider from `/oauth` to `http://localhost:8080/oauth` and now it is as excepted.

┳━┳ ヽ(ಠل͜ಠ)ﾉ